# Does position of resistor matter in this schematic?

Tags: arduino

This is the schematic:
[image: Arduino-Schematic]

Above picture is the crystal resonator part of Arduino ATMEGA328P micro-controller, in the green rectangle they placed the resistor in parallel **before** the crystal and in Arduino UNO also it's before the crystal.

1. What does this resistor do?
2. Does the position of the resistor matter? can i place it **after** the crystal?
3. Why crystal is so close to the chip in Arduino UNO?

Comment: schematic diagrams do not show physical positioning of components

Comment: @jsotola i know but in Arduino board it IS before the crystal, just making sure before making the standalone Arduino...

Comment: @newbie The xtal and the two capacitors must be as close as possible to the pins. The resistor is much less important to be close by, as the parasitic resistance of the traces are tiny compared to the resistor value.

Comment: The schematic doesn't show a good physical layout. Those two caps should be nice and close to the pins with the crystal not far away. It makes no difference where that resistor is. You also potentially don't even need the crystal, but depends on what you're doing.

Comment: I think the resistor should be inverted.... lol...  no isn't it already internal to the ATmega?  @newbie ... because if you need 10 ppm accuracy distance on traces can add pF which lowers frequency.  REad the Section 9 of the datasheet, dont copy someone else's design

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 I'm just a "hobbyist" not some electronic engineer! break it to parts please...

Comment: the Resistor does nothing it is redundant for DC self bias and is included inside when configured to run in high or low power mode Xtal Osc. Delete. R2

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 thanks, and why crystal should be so close to the chip? post an answer please.

Comment: @newbie  to reduce sensitivity to radiated noise, phase noise injected ( if one cared about phase noise) and stray capacitance (pF) that slows down crystal by ppm ( if you cared about accuracy)  For the same reason decoupling caps are put close to each IC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the frequency that a trace is operating at, it is either 'long', or 'short'.

If it is 'short', then it's a 'node'. All points of the connection are at the same voltage. It has a stray capacitance to ground, which is roughly proportional to length. The order of components along the connection on the schematic has no relation to their order on the PCB - why should it, they're all at the same voltage.

If it is 'long', say more than 1/10th of a wavelength, then you need to consider the transmission line effects. The voltage varies along the trace. The order of components matters. It has an impedance which is constant, not a capacitance. A line like this tends to be drawn differently on a schematic, not a simple thin connection, but a thick line, usually with a note about its impedance.

At 16MHz, these crystal oscillator connections are very short, so they are simply nodes. PCB ordering does not matter. In this particular case, a crystal oscillator needs to minimise the stray capacitance at each terminal, so the traces need to be physically short to achieve that. The resistor goes electrically in parallel with the crystal, and it is left to the PCB layout designer whether it's easier, physically, which way round to lay out the crystal and the resistor.

Typically this resistor provides DC continuity across the crystal, in order to bias the amplifier on the chip that makes it oscillate. Some chips provide this resistor internally, some don't.

Comment: Most uC I’ve seen including every ATMega include internal self bias R’s